# How can I view my Google Analytics data on Android?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to view the Google Analytics of my web sites on my Android 2.1 mobile phone. How can I view my Google Analytics data on Android?

Comment: I received a very good asnwer from Bryan Denny, but has anyone got a recemondation which application to choose ? There are soo many ... thx

Comment: No one ? No experience with one of the applicaitons ? There are so many , it's hard to choose (and you never know what they do in the background ). So I certainly would appreciated some experience of other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer to my own question (which I re-discovered just now), I can tell I have installed:

- [mAnaltyics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mugitek.analytics) : gives you several charts and data of all your web sites coupled to you Google account. Very nice.
- [Analytics Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.widget.analytics) : widget which when clicked, will update one count of one of your sites . Different widgets can be created. Very handy to follow the most important data.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, they now have their very own [Google Analytics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.giant) app. Enjoy!

Description from Google Play:

> Essential data for your sites & apps. Anywhere, anytime. The Google
>   Analytics app shows what is new and what is important on your Google
>   Analytics profiles. See real time statistics, customizable dashboards
>   and intelligence events on your phone.

Comment: duplicate: same as Al Everett's answer, don't know who was first though...

Answer (score 3):

There is now an [official Google Analytics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.giant) app. It requires Android 2.1 or greater.

[Blog announcement](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/06/data-at-your-fingertips-announcing.html?m=1)

Comment: duplicate: same as jlehenbauer's answer, don't know who was first though...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried any of [these applications on the market](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=google+analytics)?

Additionally, you should be able to see most of the data via the web except for their graphs (which uses Flash, you'd need Android 2.2 to view those).

Comment: just received my Samsung Galaxy S this week and it's my first Android device. So I'm looking around for all sorts of things (sites where to buy/download applications, good books for develoment and so on ... thanks for pointing me to this site.

Comment: @Edelcom congrats on your first Android device and welcome to Android! Appbrain is a good site to search for apps in the market.  Dev books, look at my answer here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/good-getting-started-book/1636#1636